# Kotlin Serialization for Generic Objects...?

Tags: json, kotlin, generics, serialization, json-deserialization

I had the bright idea to implement a generic object and attempt to serialize / deserialize it, and received this error:

```
Serializer for class 'DetailsRequest' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
```

I thought the @Serializer annotation would have achieved this... ???

The implementation of the data class, and its custom serializer (which is probably overkill), are as follows:

```
@Serializable(with=DetailsRequestSerializer::class)
data class DetailsRequest<out T>(val details: T)

object DetailsRequestSerializer : KSerializer<DetailsRequest<*>> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = buildClassSerialDescriptor(
        "DetailsRequest") {
        when (this::class) {
            String::class -> element<String>("details")
            Long::class -> element<Long>("details")
            Int::class -> element<Int>("details")
            Double::class -> element<Double>("details")
            Float::class -> element<Float>("details")
            else -> element<String>("details")
        }
    }

    override fun serialize(
        encoder: Encoder,
        value: DetailsRequest<*>
    ) {
        value.details.let {
            encoder.encodeStructure(descriptor) {
                when (value::class) {
                    String::class -> encodeStringElement(descriptor, 0, value.details as String)
                    Long::class -> encodeLongElement(descriptor, 0, value.details as Long)
                    Int::class -> encodeIntElement(descriptor, 0, value.details as Int)
                    Double::class -> encodeDoubleElement(descriptor, 0, value.details as Double)
                    Float::class -> encodeFloatElement(descriptor, 0, value.details as Float)
                    else -> encodeStringElement(descriptor, 0, value.details as String)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): DetailsRequest<*> {
        return when (this::class) {
            String::class -> DetailsRequest(decoder.decodeString())
            Long::class -> DetailsRequest(decoder.decodeLong())
            Int::class -> DetailsRequest(decoder.decodeInt())
            Double::class -> DetailsRequest(decoder.decodeDouble())
            Float::class -> DetailsRequest(decoder.decodeFloat())
            else -> DetailsRequest(decoder.decodeString())
        }
    }
}
```

I have written this unit test:

```
class PlaygroundTest {
    private val json = Json {
        encodeDefaults = true
        isLenient = true
        allowSpecialFloatingPointValues = true
        allowStructuredMapKeys = true
        prettyPrint = true
        useArrayPolymorphism = false
        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
    }

    @Test
    fun `Details Integration Tests`() {
        val input = DetailsRequest(details = "New Record")
        val value = json.encodeToString(input)
        println("value=[$value]")
        val output = value.convertToDataClass<DetailsRequest<String>>()
        println("output=[$output]")
    }

    @OptIn(InternalSerializationApi::class)
    internal inline fun <reified R : Any> String.convertToDataClass() =
        json.decodeFromString(R::class.serializer(), this)
}
```

Bonus points: This is a Kotlin Multiplatform project, which I do not believe will impact this situation.

Is this type of situation even possible?

Answer (score 6):

## The problem you asked about

Good news: this situation is totally possible, and your code is very nearly correct. Kotlin's builtin serialization is a bit wonky about getting serializers, though, so it is a bit surprising at first that your code snippet doesn't work.

The answer lies in a bit of almost fine print in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/serializer.html)<sup>[1]</sup>:

> **Constraints**
>
> This paragraph explains known (but not all!) constraints of the serializer() implementation. Please note that they are not bugs, but implementation restrictions that we cannot workaround.
>
> [...]
>
> - Serializers for classes with generic parameters are ignored by this method

Since `DetailsRequest<out T>` has that generic `out T`, this means that accessing its serializer through `DetailsRequest::class.serializer()` won't work.

Fortunately, `kotlinx.serialization` provides us [a different method](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-core/kotlinx.serialization/serializer.html)<sup>[2]</sup> to get a serializer for an arbitrary type:

```kotlin
inline fun <T> serializer(): KSerializer<T>
```

In your case, you could use it like this:

```kotlin
// OptIn no longer needed
internal inline fun <reified R : Any> String.convertToDataClass() =
    json.decodeFromString(serializer<R>(), this)
```

Note that there's an overload of `json.decodeFromString` that uses serializer() automatically: all you really need is

```kotlin
internal inline fun <reified R : Any> String.convertToDataClass() =
    json.decodeFromString<R>(this)
```

(In fact, at this point, you may even consider removing the convertToDataClass method entirely.)

## The problem you didn't ask about

If you run the code with that change, you'll get a different error:

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 0: Expected beginning of the string, but got {
JSON input: {
    "details": "New Record"
}
```

This is simply because your implementation of the deserializer is a bit off—it's trying to deserialize DetailsRequest as a single string (such as `"New Record"`) rather than a full JSON object the way you serialized it (such as `{ "details": "New Record" }`).

A full explanation of the issue here would take a bit more space than is reasonable for this answer, but I refer you to the very complete—if a bit long—serialization guide [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/serializers.md#custom-serializers-for-a-generic-type). You may need to scroll up and read the rest of the Custom Serializers section to ensure you understand it all as well.

## A quicker solution

If you mark `DetailsRequest` with simply `@Serializable` (without the `with` argument) and remove the entire `DetailsRequestSerializer` object, the code will run fine and serialize and deserialize as one would expect. The `@Serializable` annotation (without a `with` argument) tells the compiler to autogenerate a serializer, which it does successfully and reasonably in this case.

Unless you have a specific serialization need that this default serializer does not fulfill, I would strongly recommend simply using the default one. It's much cleaner and a lot less work. :-)

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>You'll have to scroll down a bit; Dokka doesn't allow me to link to a specific declaration of a function. The relevant bit is all the way at the bottom.</sub>

<sup>[2]</sup> <sub>Yes, it's on the same page in the documentation. Just don't scroll down this time. :-)</sub>

Comment: Well. I'll be damn... It was that simple. That's crazy. And it pays to actually READ The F***** Manual and actually FOLLOW the examples provided. My approach was unnecessary. That inline method you provided was critical over here. You are incredible! I as able to process the dumbed-down narrative. Thank you so much! you are my hero!!!

Comment: @Rohen Giralt, most of the times we get a `Boolean/String/JsonObjects` in responses, in all your examples, you "know" the type before hand, is there an elegant way to check before doing `Json.decodeFromString<String>`e.g. when the type is a boolean?